# linker error when not starting with "HelloWorld" scene

Tags: c++, macos, linker, cocos2d-x

I've just started to use Cocos2d-x c++ (Version 3.4), and I'm trying to build a simple game for Mac, but when I change this line in AppDelegate.cpp

```
auto scene = HelloWorld::createScene();
```

to my custom Scene

```
auto scene = KeyboardScene::createScene();
```

I get this linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "KeyboardScene::createScene()", referenced from:
      AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching() in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).
```

I can't figure out know what I'm missing here, any help is appreciated, thank you.

If you want to see the custom class source visit:

http://pastebin.com/F0NhSUWf

Comment: Did you include `KeyboardScene.h` in AppDelegate? You've got duplicated code in the pastebin, that could be related.

Comment: Not an `#include` issue, as the code compiles, but does not link. Make sure you're linking to the right `.dynlib` for x86_64 (and not for IOS arm)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This probably can be result of one of two things.

First. You do not define `KeyboardScene::createScene()` symbol at all. Check that you actually have the definition of `KeyboardScene:: createScene()` in you `KeyboardScene.cpp` file. You `KeyboardScene.cpp` should contain code like this:

```
KeyboardScene::createScene() {
    // function body here
}
```

Second. You do not compile `KeyboardScene.cpp` or do not link resulting `KeyboardScene.o` into the executable. Check that `KeyboardScene.cpp` is included to build set of the application target as in the sample here. [image: Sample image]

Comment: Thank you, Xcode included it only in the iOS target by default.

Comment: How's about static folder (blue icon) ?